# Define Asset Catalog at runtime

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I want to know if its possible to define which asset catalog at run time.

Ideally I'd like to have assetsA.xcassets and assetsB.xcassets and define which one to use at runtime.

All the image sets will have the same names, eg bgPattern but would look slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

This should / may do what you need...

```
init?(named name: String, in bundle: Bundle?, 
        compatibleWith traitCollection: UITraitCollection?)
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624154-init